# addEventListener вызывается два раза при переборе через forEach

Tags: javascript

Код очень простой, обычно у меня это работало, но не в данном случаи, таких же переменных нету, названия менял. Вот код из-за которого всё и ломается:

```
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.calendarBlock__slide');

slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
  let ids = slide.querySelectorAll('.calendar__checkInput');

  ids.forEach((id, x) => {
    let type = id.getAttribute('data-type');
    let label = id.parentNode;
    let number = `s${i+1}${type}`;

    id.setAttribute('id', number);
    label.setAttribute('for', number);
  });
})
```

Вот код с перебором:

```js
let labels = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar__type');
labels.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(item)
    item.classList.toggle('active');
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="calendar__types">
  <label for="" class="calendar__type calendar__type_green">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calendar__checkInput" data-type='1' id="">
      <span class="calendar__checkBlock">
        <img src="./assets/img/check.svg" alt="" class="svg calendar__checkIcon">
      </span>
      <span class="calendar__name">Начало торгов </span>
      <span class="calendar__number">32</span>
    </label>
  <label for="" class="calendar__type calendar__type_lightBlue">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calendar__checkInput" data-type='2' id="">
      <span class="calendar__checkBlock">
        <img src="./assets/img/check.svg" alt="" class="svg calendar__checkIcon">
      </span>
      <span class="calendar__name">Окончание тихого периода</span>
      <span class="calendar__number">17</span>
    </label>
  <label for="" class="calendar__type calendar__type_yellow">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calendar__checkInput" data-type='3' id="">
      <span class="calendar__checkBlock">
        <img src="./assets/img/check.svg" alt="" class="svg calendar__checkIcon">
      </span>
      <span class="calendar__name">Lockup (6 мес)</span>
      <span class="calendar__number">14</span>
    </label>
  <label for="" class="calendar__type calendar__type_yellow">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calendar__checkInput" data-type='4' id="">
      <span class="calendar__checkBlock">
        <img src="./assets/img/check.svg" alt="" class="svg calendar__checkIcon">
      </span>
      <span class="calendar__name">Lockup (3 мес)</span>
      <span class="calendar__number">10</span>
    </label>
  <label for="" class="calendar__type calendar__type_blue">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calendar__checkInput" data-type='5' id="">
      <span class="calendar__checkBlock">
        <img src="./assets/img/check.svg" alt="" class="svg calendar__checkIcon">
      </span>
      <span class="calendar__name">Отчетный день</span>
      <span class="calendar__number">15</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

И таких блоков несколько, и каждый из таких блоков расположен в разных calendarBlock__slide. Id у всех элементов уникальный

Comment: как связан первый код со вторым? В какой момент что вызывается? Какая разметка для приведенного кода? Почему ты думаешь, что вызывается два раза? Почему не должно вызываться два раза?

Comment: В общем этот код никак особо не связан. В первом примере добавляется for, для label, во втором примере я отслеживаю клик по этому label. Во втором примере кода есть console.log, который при клике на label вызывается два раза

Comment: все зависит от разметки к которой этот код применяется

Comment: А зачем это делать 2 раза? Почему не повесить слушатель в первом цикле, если перебираете одни и теже элементы?

Comment: Он перебирает разные элементы

Comment: Разметку приложил

Comment: @Vashka, перенес твой код в сниппет. При клике выводится только одна строка лога. Можешь изменить код так, чтобы ошибка воспроизводилась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**. После непродолжительной беседы. Пришлите к [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684017/avoiding-the-double-event-when-labels-are-clicked-within-an-element-with-a-cli).

> clicking on a LABEL will bubble-up a click event. The solution appears
> to be to check to see if the event was triggered by the label

Решение, нужно проверить, было ли событие инициировано меткой.

```
let labels = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar__type');
labels.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if(event.target.nodeName == 'LABEL'){
       console.log(item)
       item.classList.toggle('active');
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: А что за минус можно как-то пояснить

Comment: id уникальный у всех элементов

Comment: i это индекс, он не может быть одинаковым у двух элементов

Comment: slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
  let ids = slide.querySelectorAll('.calendar__checkInput');
  ids.forEach((id, x) => {. Вот отсюда мне это не кажется таким

Comment: ок, но оно является уникальным у каждого элемента. label у каждого элемента сам по себе работает

Comment: Ок если уникальное то я снимаю ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116778/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-vashka).